# How to use dbt run twice for sql serve r?

Tags: mysql, sql, dbt

I was trying to connect dbt and my SQL sever and it went successful but now when I am running dbt run twice on second I am heaving error. What is the solution for that .

Comment: What is "dbt"? Strings file of DBASE table? PS. MySQL <> SQL Server. Select one of...

Comment: It's a run that we can use for running dbt service or model you can say

Comment: @KundanSingh can you show the error you're getting?